# UISegmentedControl, 7+, set widths -- no longer centres

Tags: uiview, uistoryboard, uisegmentedcontrol

This is 7+ only,

Make a UISegmentedControl with say four segments, in Storyboard sit in in the middle of the iPhone (it'll be about 200 wide),

run the app, and of course it is centered.

I'm simply forcing the widths of each item like this...

[image]

(all are the same)

Now run the app - bizarrely it no longer centers!

It gives the impression it keeps the Left of the control in the same place, and then calculates it's width "whatever" based on setting those "Segment-Width" items.  And then the right end is way too far to the right!  It would appear it does not reposition (i.e., center) the control after changing the width.

Is there a solution?

(At the moment I simply "move it the necessary amount to the left!" which is lame.)  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

That's the way it works because in the View section of the Size inspector the x position of the segmented control is fixed.